# Inferring space domain signal from 2D DFT

Tags: fourier-transform, 2d

By just looking at the 2D Fourier Transform of a signal, can it every be known precisely which values in the space domain are zero?

Comment: Couldn't you just do an inverse Fourier transform? Then you would know precisely.

Comment: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/fourier.htm